# How to make it a monad?

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scala-cats

I am trying to validate a list of strings sequentially and define the validation result type like that:

```
import cats._, cats.data._, cats.implicits._

case class ValidationError(msg: String)
type ValidationResult[A] =  Either[NonEmptyList[ValidationError], A]
type ListValidationResult[A] = ValidationResult[List[A]] // not a monad :(
```

I would like to make `ListValidationResult` a monad. Should I implement `flatMap` and `pure` manually or there is an easier way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a totally different approach leveraging `cats` `Validated`:

```scala
import cats.data.Validated.{ invalidNel, valid }

val stringList: List[String] = ???

def evaluateString(s: String): ValidatedNel[ValidationError, String] =
  if (???) valid(s) else invalidNel(ValidationError(s"invalid $s"))

val validationResult: ListValidationResult[String] = 
  stringList.map(evaluateString).sequenceU.toEither
```

It can be adapted for a generic type `T`, as per your example.

---

Notes:

- `val stringList: List[String] = ???` is the list of strings you want to validate;
- `ValidatedNel[A,B]` is just a type alias for `Validated[NonEmptyList[A],B]`;
- `evaluateString` should be your evaluation function, it is currently just an unimplemented stub `if`;
- `sequenceU` you may want to read `cats` documentation about it: [sequenceU](http://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Traverse.html#sequenceU[GA](fga:F[GA])(implicitU:cats.Unapply[cats.Applicative,GA]):U.M[F[U.A]]);
- `toEither` does exactly what you think it does, it converts a `Validated[A,B]` to an `Either[A,B]`.

---

As @Michael pointed out, you could also use [`traverseU`](http://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Traverse.html#traverseU[A,GB](fa:F[A])(f:A=%3EGB)(implicitU:cats.Unapply[cats.Applicative,GB]):U.M[F[U.A]]) instead of `map` and `sequenceU`

```scala
val validationResult: ListValidationResult[String] = 
  stringList.traverseU(evaluateString).toEither
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I forgot about it. It's possible to use `traverse` (or `traverseU`) instead of `map` and `sequence` (`sequenceU`).

Comment: I need to clarify my question: suppose I need to make sure that the input  `"a"`, `"b"`, and `one of more "c"`. Suppose you three functions: `String => ValidatedNel[ValidationError, String]` to check if a given string is "a", "b", or  "c". How would you validate a list ?

Comment: I will probably write another question about it.

Comment: see my new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215145/validating-list-of-strings