# Validating list of strings

Tags: scala, validation, monads, parser-combinators, scala-cats

This is a follow up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211940/how-to-make-it-a-monad).
Suppose I need to write a function `validate` in order to make sure that a given list of strings consists of "a", "b", and one or more "c".

```
def validate(ss: List[String]): Either[NonEmptyList[MyError], Unit] = ???
```

Suppose I have three functions to check if a given string is "a", "b", or "c":

```
def validateA(str: String): Either[MyError, Unit] = ???
def validateB(str: String): Either[MyError, Unit] = ???
def validateC(str: String): Either[MyError, Unit] = ???
```

How to compose those functions to implement `validate` ?

One solution is a "parser combinators" approach. Define a monad instance for type `Validator = Either[NonEmptyList[MyError], List[String]]`, combinators like `oneOrMore` similar to parser combinators etc.

I am wondering whether there is an easier solution.

Comment: Are they sorted? Can you rely on positions to do the validation? (e.g. first must be an `a`, second must be a `b` and then one or more `c`)

Comment: Instead to use ``Unit``, can you use a ADT ? One tip for your problem, take a loot to the function ``orElse``.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to leverage `cats` `Validated`.

Let's define some helper methods, if you really don't want to change your `validateT` methods signatures:

```scala
def validateA_(str: String): ValidatedNel[MyError, Unit] = validateA(str).toValidatedNel
def validateB_(str: String): ValidatedNel[MyError, Unit] = validateB(str).toValidatedNel
def validateC_(str: String): ValidatedNel[MyError, Unit] = validateC(str).toValidatedNel
```

Then you can implement a `validate_` helper function:

```scala
import cats.data.Validated.{ invalidNel, valid }

def validate_(ss: List[String]): ValidatedNel[MyError, Unit] = ss match {
  case a :: b :: c if c.nonEmpty =>
    validateA_(a) combine validateB_(b) combine c.traverseU_(validateC_)
  case _ => invalidNel(MyError(???)) //List too short
}
```

And finally implement your `validate` function as:

```scala
def validate(ss: List[String]): Either[NonEmptyList[MyError], Unit] = 
  validate_(ss).toEither
```

Assumptions: the input list is sorted and if it is shorter than `3` elements a specific error (e.g. list too short) is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you ! I am afraid though this solution is not generic enough. What if I need to check of the list consists of `one or more a` and then `one or more b` ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you could make use of [Scalactic](http://www.scalactic.org/user_guide/OrAndEvery), which allows one to accumulate errors without short-circuiting the whole validation process.

This [example](http://www.scalactic.org/user_guide/OrAndEvery) looks quite similar to what you are trying to do. Check it out!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! Did not hear about this library.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope this is what you were looking for.